# Зачем нужно кастить переменную к типу void?

Tags: c

Изучаю код dnsmasq. Там есть код, в котором у меня возникают вопросы. Приведу свой пример.

```
void process ( int pos, int black, int brave ) {
  (void)pos;
  (void)black;
  (void)brave;
}
```

для чего пишут так `(void)pos`?

Comment: Чтоб компилятор не ругался на неиспользованный параметр...

Comment: В качестве алтернативы в GCC можно использовать `__attribute__((unused))`.

Comment: Понятно, спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как уже сказали коллеги в комментариях, это способ избежать
предупреждений от компилятора.  Иногда это нужно в качестве временной
меры, а иногда — чтобы явно показать, что вы
намеренно пропускаете результат.  См. полезные вопросы с АнглоСО:

- [*Why cast unused return values to void?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/689677/1892060)
- [*Casting to void doesn't remove warn_unused_result error*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3614691/1892060)
- [*Casting function returns to void*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3998802/1892060)